# uTorrent slow upload speed with eSata

Tags: speed, performance, utorrent, esata

I noticed that my torrents won't seed at all if I connect my external HDD with a eSATA connection. I switched it back to USB and it's working perfectly fine now. With eSATA it does upload but at a VERY low speed (50kB/s) and there will be times when it's a little faster. My max upload speed is 10MB/s. Both USB and eSATA gives the same drive letter.

HDD: WD7500BPVT

uTorrent: 2.2

Comment: Are you sure it's only the drive connections and not the torrents or time of day? Upload speeds can be all over the place.

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out that disabling disk caching in uTorrent solves it. (uncheck the boxes under: Options> Preferences> Advanced> Disk Cache)

Answer (score 0):

When you say working fine on the USB i'm assuming you mean uploading faster than 50kb/s. Having made that assumption check the the configuration of the drive when it is plugged in with eSATA. Try enabling Better Performance mode. I have found this to increase read and write speed. It may be enabled when setup with USB but not with eSATA.

1. Device Manager
2. Right Click on the drive
3. Click Properties
4. Go to the polices tab

Comment: Doesn't help :( . I think my HDD go into "sleep" mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows there is a chance that the torrent program might be trying to access the drive letter assigned to the USB. Do you get different driveletters assigned depending on if you use ESATA or USB ?!
Make sure your torrent program is accessing the file from the correct place.